# How to store value in LocalStorage in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am new at React Native and I am creating an app in which I need to store values in local storage like **SharedPref** in Android .

**Ex:** If user loggedIn then control should go to Dashboard otherwise login screen should appear

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 61):

There are several options to do such thing.

For most basic things you can use [AsyncStorage](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage) from react-native, but there are other options, like [Realm](https://github.com/realm/realm-js) and [SQLite](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage) that are libraries to store data on device.

If you are using [Redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux), you can also use redux-persist.

**EDIT**

As @honor said, you should use [react-native-community/react-native-async-storage](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-async-storage) instead of the older AsyncStorage referenced here (deprecated)

Answer (score 24):

For anyone who is still looking for this, RN [async storage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html) has been deprecated. You can use this: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-async-storage instead.

Comment: Can it be used with Expo?

Comment: @NikolaMihajlović, `AsyncStorage` can be used with Expo.

Comment: RN's default one yes, a replacement `react-native-async-storage` (suggested by this answer) still no, unfortunately.

Answer (score 8):

AsyncStorage is best option to store some data you can use like below example:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('access_token', responseData.data.access_token);
```

This is my separate component where you can create a separate function for import any where example:

```
export const isSignedIn = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem(USER_KEY)
      .then(res => {
        if (res !== null) {
          resolve(res);
        } else {
          resolve(false);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => reject(err));
  });
};
```

How to import?

```
import { isSignedIn, url } from "./Auth";

isSignedIn()
    .then(res => {
      this.changeLoaderStatus();
      if(res){
        res; //this is your token 
      }
    }
```

You will get the package from below URL:

https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage

Answer (score 8):

you can use [sync storage](https://medium.com/@sajjadintel/react-native-sync-storage-c69062c234f) that is easier to use than async storage:

```
import SyncStorage from 'sync-storage';

...

SyncStorage.set('foo', 'bar');

const result = SyncStorage.get('foo');
console.log(result); // 'bar'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `LocalStorage` in React-Native, you can use [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html) instead.

Edit : You can also use a store like [redux](https://redux.js.org/) to handle this.

Comment: Save data on Store on Redux is only temporal.

Comment: @BrayanLoayza You can use redux-persist to keep your redux state or a part of it using one of the storage engines from this list : https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#storage-engines

Answer (score 1):

Don't use AsyncStorage, as there are numerous bugs on Android, and it doesn't seem the RN teams has any interest in fixing it (been several years like that).

In short: don't use AsyncStorage

Comment: I use Redux with the Redux-Persist middleware.

Comment: @Spock redux-persist uses AsyncStorage

Answer (score 1):

From the react native docs :

AsyncStorage is Deprecated.

It suggest use of react-native-async-storage.

Link of docs:  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html

Hope you are clear.

Answer (score 1):

According to official [doc](http://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage.html) `AsyncStorage` has been deprecated and now `@react-native-community/async-storage` will be used
so, follow steps below to use `AsyncStorage`

> yarn add @react-native-community/async-storage
>
> cd ios/ && pod install (For IOS only)

**Storing Data**

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

storeData = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', 'stored value')
  } catch (e) {
    // saving error
  }
}
```

**Reading Data**

```
getData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
    if(value !== null) {
      // value previously stored
    }
  } catch(e) {
    // error reading value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

used AsyncStorage

and perform all your local storage operation like get and set value in react native

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, we used `AsyncStorage` in the initial stages. However, we have moved to [react-native-mmkv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mmkv) mainly due to a performance comparison between the two.

Though they both are key-value storages and since react-native is slowly moving into new C++-backed fabric architecture, MMKV makes a better choice due to these 3 primary reasons -

- High performance because everything is written in C++
- ~30x faster than AsyncStorage
- Uses JSI instead of the "old" Bridge

Feel free to see the detailed comparison info [here](https://adityaputraprat.medium.com/react-native-mmkv-vs-dc3647c9656a).

Comment: i started using mmkv but it does not work with remote debugging tools like react-native-debugger - which is a must in my case..

Comment: Flipper is the way to go it seems