# How to save users response on the client side of React Native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux

I am trying to implement a voting system in React Native. Currently I have a `FlatList` that shows a card with two images with two text fields. I would like that when a user clicks the text it registers as a vote and greys out the text. I can handle to code to grey out and de-activate the text but how can I make sure that when the user closes and reopens that it remains that way. If I use Redux will that Achieve what I am trying to do? I just want to be sure that users cannot double vote for something. I thought about storing the userId's of those who have voted in firestore but would prefer to limit the number of calls to the database as possible.

Here is the code to my `FlatList`

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.data}
  renderItem={({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Card style={styles.listItem}>
          <Text style={styles.infoText}>{item.userName}</Text>
          <View style={styles.cardView}>
            <Image
              style={styles.postIcon}
              source={
                item.imageUrl === "empty"
                  ? require("../assets/icon.png")
                  : { uri: item.firstImageUrl }
              }
            />
            <Image
              style={styles.postIcon}
              source={
                item.imageUrl === "empty"
                  ? require("../assets/icon.png")
                  : { uri: item.secondImageUrl }
              }
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.infoContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Text>{item.firstImageTitle}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Text>{item.secondImageTitle}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </Card>
      </View>
    );
  }}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
/>;
```

Comment: You should use `AsyncStorage` or if you're using Redux you can use `redux-persist`. Check this answer for details - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47509558/how-to-store-value-in-localstorage-in-react-native

Comment: Thank you very much I will be doing that.