# Local Storage - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, local-storage

As Async Storage is deprecated what other way is there to store a variable locally??

I have a React Native ios App with a Notification Centre. 
Each time the user enters the Notification Centre a Cognito access Token was generated. To avoid excess of token generation the Tokens were saved through Async storage and their expiry was checked. 
Now is there some other local storage in React Native that i can use??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store value in LocalStorage in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47509558/how-to-store-value-in-localstorage-in-react-native)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Async storage is not deprecated its moved to a separate package which you can install and use

https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage/

Or for tokens you can use react-native-keychain which is a way secure package you can check it here.
https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain

Comment: Haven't worked on `react-native`, but is there any particular reason why they don't use `localStorage`?

Comment: from what i know, RN uses Async storage from the beginning as it designed for mobiles and it handles the storage according the platform

Comment: @Guru https://reactnative.dev/docs/security : according to the React Native docs, Async storage is not for Token storage. As you mentioned ios can use Keychain and android can use shared preferences. Never used it before!!! some insight on Keychain and shared preferences pleasee??? is this the syntax "Keychain.setGenericPassword('token', token)" to store the Token in keychain?????

Comment: You can get an idea from this blog https://medium.com/react-native-training/securing-your-react-native-app-using-keychain-6de10850d203 as you can see in the docs you shared this library is recommended

Answer (score 2):

It is moved to [@react-native-community/async-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/async-storage)

Install it and import it from lib:

```js
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
```

Answer (score 1):

**AsyncStorage is deprecated so use below package**

Get library With Yarn:

```
yarn add @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
```

**Once done, import the header**

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
```

**For store a value**

```
const storeData = async (value) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', value)
  } catch (e) {
    // saving error
  }
}
```

**Get a Value**

```
const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
    if(value !== null) {
      // value previously stored
    }
  } catch(e) {
    // error reading value
  }
}
```

For more: [offical link](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage)

Answer (score 0):

Async storage from `react-native` library is deprecated, they split it from react-native core into a community library.

You can always use Async Storage from this [library](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage)

Just follow installation steps from [docs](https://react-native-community.github.io/async-storage/docs/install). And you can import `AsyncStorage` like this

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
```

Comment: Haven't worked on react-native, but is there any particular reason why they don't use localStorage?

Comment: LocalStorage stores data in web browser, since react native allows to build mobile apps we cannot use localStorage. Async Storage is used to natively store key-value globally to the app