# How do i use localstorage in React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a web app that I want to convert to an native app with react native.

So I started the project and all the logic is the same as the web-app but i don't know how to use the local storage of the app instead the browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47509558/how-to-store-value-in-localstorage-in-react-native

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store value in LocalStorage in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47509558/how-to-store-value-in-localstorage-in-react-native)

Answer (score 1):

you can't use localstorage in react native.
Asyncstorage is provided in react-native.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage

You can install package for that from this link.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage

Hope this will help you.